# Angular Elements: How to use multiple Angular Elements in non angular application

Tags: angular, angular-elements

I have created multiple angular elements like below:

1. app-first-element
2. app-second-element
3. app-third-element

When I use these multiple elements  and try render in non angular application (i.e a simple blank html project)  only one element is being bootstrapped, rest of the elements  are not being bootstrapped.

Here is the example poc I am customizing https://github.com/BioPhoton/ng-elements-poc

What I have customized?

1. seperated  `vendorChunk`  from angular.json  so that  I can use same vendor.js with multiple elements
2. Using common polyfills to reduce the burden or to avoid unwanted js errors

**Question:**

1. How to isolate the `ngBootstrap` to render the element to its scope alone.

**What I have tried:**

1. Tried creating app specific  platformFactory which could theoretically solve the problem

`const myPlatformFactory1 = createPlatformFactory(platformBrowserDynamic, 'app1');
 myPlatformFactory1().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(err => console.log(err));`

Thanks in Advance.